# How to use MySQLi inside a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, mysqli

MySQLi works fine inside a class with no namespace and outside a class.

I recently started using namespace and now I have stumbled on a code much like the following:

```
 namespace Project;

 class ProjectClass{

      public static function ProjectClassFunction{
          $db = new mysql(data, data, data, data);
      }

 }
```

However, it reports back to me with a message

> "Fatal error: Class 'Project\mysqli' not found"

How do I use mysqli inside a class which uses namespace?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By default, PHP will try to load classes from your current namespace. Refer to the class in the global namespace:

```
$db = new \mysqli(/* ... */);
```

This is the same thing you'd do when referring to a class in a different namespace:

```
$foo = new \Some\Namespace\Foo();
```

Note that if you left off the beginning backslash, PHP would try to load the class relative to your current namespace. The following code will look in the namespace `Project\Some\Namespace` for a class named `Foo`:

```
namespace Project;
$foo = new Some\Namespace\Foo();
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly import namespaces and save yourself ambiguity:

```
namespace Project;

use Mysqli;

class ProjectClass
{
    public static function ProjectClassFunction()
    {
        $db = new Mysqli(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me… :/